Plotly.js component not re-rendering in React when state changes
I'm using react-plotly.js to render a plot in my React application. I have a Zustand store to manage the state of my plot data and layout. When I click a button to fetch new data and update the state, the Plot component does not re-render with the new data. Here is my setup:
store.js
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { immer } from 'zustand/middleware/immer'

const useStore = create(immer((set) => ({
  data: [
    {
      x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      y: [2, 6, 3, 8, 5],
      type: 'bar',
      marker: { color: 'blue' },
    },
  ],
  layout: {
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    title: 'A Different Plot',
  },
  setData: (newData) => set((state) => {
    console.log("Updating data:", newData);
    state.data = newData;
  }),
  setLayout: (newLayout) => set((state) => {
    console.log("Updating layout:", newLayout);
    state.layout = newLayout;
  }),
})))

export default useStore

App.jsx
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js'
import useStore from './store'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const data = useStore(state => state.data)
  const layout = useStore(state => state.layout)
  const setData = useStore(state => state.setData)
  const setLayout = useStore(state => state.setLayout)

  const fetchData = async () => {
    console.log("Fetching data...");
    const fakeData = [
      {
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y: [2, 6, 3, 8, 5],
        type: 'bar',
        marker: { color: 'blue' },
      },
    ];
    const fakeLayout = {
      width: 700,
      height: 400,
      title: 'A Different Plot 5',
    };

    setData(fakeData);
    setLayout(fakeLayout);
    console.log("Data fetched and set:", { fakeData, fakeLayout });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && layout) {
      console.log("Data and layout are ready!");
    }
  }, [data, layout]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Load Plot</button>
      {data && layout ? (
          <Plot key={JSON.stringify({ data, layout })} data={data} layout={layout} />
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default App

I have tried adding a key prop to the Plot component to force it to re-render, but it still doesn't update with the new data. What am I missing? How can I ensure that the Plot component re-renders when the state changes?
